# Silverlight Bing Map control does not render when deployed

Tags: silverlight, render, bing-maps

The SL app works just fine rendering all the pushpins only when executed thru VS2010. When I deploy the app to a local web server, the Map comes up but no data is rendered. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a credentials key?

Comment: Thank you Derek. Yes I am using a map key. I tried changing the key type to other than DEV, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your silverlight application connecting to a localhost web service for the data? Have you used Fiddler to verify that your web service calls are going to the production server? This setting is in your ServiceReferences.ClientConfig file in your Silverlight project. You can also unzip your xap to verify the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Derek, yes. I have a DEV key for the map. Then I tried changing the Key type but that did not work.

Andy, yes I did use Fiddler but did not tell me anything :)

The SL app within the SLN connects to the WS as a project ref. When I deployed locally, I did deploy the SL and the WS. The WS works just fine locally (localhost). After I deployed the SL app, I had to change URL in the Service Ref file. I initially changed it to the localhost location and that is when I posted the question originally.

Then, I changed the URL to the Hosted version of the WS and it now works. So the fact that works is good; but still wondering why the SL app pointing to the working version of the WS (localhost) does not work.